# How can I change values to NaN in a pandas dataframe for specific rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently calculating the cash to price ratio of about 19,000 companies over the last 10 years. I have this all on one data frame and have 20+ variables. The problem I'd like to solve is to have the rolling sum restart once a new stock ticker is introduced. The way I coded below causes the first three entries of a new stock to also sum the Q_Cashflow of the stock just before it in the column.

I coded as follows:

```
df['K_Cashflow'] = df.Q_Cashflow.rolling(4).sum()
df['cash-to-price'] = df['K_Cashflow']/df['Market Cap']
```

The output is :

```
   Ticker Symbol    |Q_Cashflow |Market Cap |cash-to-price  |K_Cashflow|
44     ADCT.1       |    16.9   |709.0700   |0.120157       |  85.2    |
45     ADCT.1       |   102.2   |718.7700   |0.310948       |  223.5   |
46     ADCT.1       |   136.6   |1231.5240  |0.260815       |  321.2   |
47     AAL          |   456.0   |3034.1766  |0.234561       |  711.7   |
48     AAL          |  1173.0   |2258.1468  |0.827138       | 1867.8   |
49     AAL          |  1090.0   |2088.2862  |1.367437       | 2855.6   |
50     AAL          |  1241.0   |2597.5755  |1.524499       | 3960.0   |
```

Lines 47:50 should be NaN for K_Cashflow.
How would I change the first three entries of K_Cashflow to Nan for every different Ticker Symbol?

Answer (score 3):

One way to accomplish this would be to create rank column based off the ticker and then assign the lowest three ranks to a nan.  Here's an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ticker': ['a'] * 7 + ['b'] * 10,
    'cash_flow': range(17),
})

# Create the rank
df['rank'] = df.groupby('ticker').rank()

# Set the first 3 instances of each ticker to nan
df.loc[df['rank'] < 4, ['cash_flow']] = np.nan

df 
   ticker  cash_flow  rank
0       a        NaN   1.0
1       a        NaN   2.0
2       a        NaN   3.0
3       a        3.0   4.0
4       a        4.0   5.0
5       a        5.0   6.0
6       a        6.0   7.0
7       b        NaN   1.0
8       b        NaN   2.0
9       b        NaN   3.0
10      b       10.0   4.0
11      b       11.0   5.0
12      b       12.0   6.0
13      b       13.0   7.0
14      b       14.0   8.0
15      b       15.0   9.0
16      b       16.0  10.0
```

Comment: That is a great suggestion and will be very helpful. I received TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable after trying to use the pandas' rank function. Is there something I need to format in my data set?